# How to mirror a filesystem structure but wo any content

Tags: linux, backup, filesystems

This is needed for backup purposes.
Just the index of the entire fs structure.
I can do such image with a FAR File Manager plugin.
How can the same be achieved in the GNUverse?

Mirroring means perfect copy, 
i.e. **tstamps**, attribs, octets etc..

Can someone cook up a script generating a tarball?

Here's the tarball example of what i'm looking for
https://share.riseup.net/#lBxT01XArYuXmsclJToJrA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No script needed, gnu cp has a specialized switch for it

```
cp --attributes-only -a sourcedir targetdir
```

Forgot the part about tar. For this, you might want to run afterwards

```
tar cfz backup.tar.gz targetdir
```

Comment: @Ro-ee Wow-wau.. The simplicity is astounding..

Comment: @Ro-ee one-liner maybe?

Comment: apart from cp --attributes-only -a sourcedir targetdir && tar cfz backup.tar.gz tagetdir && rm -r targetdir, which only concatenates the three commands (a final cleanup added), I’m not sure tar has a mode of directly creating empty entries without the need for cp, and I don’t know if cp’s output can be put directly to use by tar...